# How to fix this in case expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, syntax-error, case

```
Select 
    ID, date_d,
    Case ID 
       when ID >= 0 then "greater" 
       else "Smaller"
    End as Grtr 
from 
    emp_date
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
>   Incorrect syntax near '>'

Input

```
ID      date_d
----------------
1   2018-02-02
2   2018-03-31
3   2019-03-31
```

Comment: Select ID,date_d,
Case 
   when ID > 0 then 'greater'
   When  ID =2 then 'between'
 Else 'Smaller'
 End as Grtr 
 from emp_date                         ---------------------------------------------------------------------------Output                                                                                               
 1 2018-02-02 greater
2 2018-03-31 greater
3 2019-03-31 greater

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **searched case expression**(original version is mixing both simple/searched syntax):

```
Select ID,date_d, Case  when ID >= 0 then 'greater' Else 'Smaller' End as Grtr 
from emp_date
```

[CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
Searched CASE expression:  
CASE  
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ]   
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ]   
END
```

Answer (score 1):

The shorthand syntax (`case expression when value ...`) is basically syntactic sugar over a list of equal conditions. If you want to use other operators, you need to use the full syntax (`case when condition then...`). E.g.:

```
Select ID,date_d,
Case 
   when ID >= 0 then 'Greater'
    Else 'Smaller'
    End as Grtr 
from emp_date
```